# The type Tree should be an instance of the typeclass Eq

Tags: haskell

I have the following data structure and want it to be an instance of the typeclass Eq.

```
data Tree n l
  = Node n (Tree n l) (Tree n l)
  | Leaf l
```

I tried to do it the following way

```
instance Eq => (Tree n l) where
  (Node a b c) == (Node d e f) = a == d
  (Leaf a) == (Leaf b) = a == b
```

But there is an error message

> ‘==’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘Tree’

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. you did not specify to what type class you made `Tree n l` an instance; and
2. in order to check that with the given definition, both `n` and `l` need to be types that are instances of the `Eq` typeclass.

So you can implement this with:

```
instance (Eq n, Eq l) => Eq (Tree n l) where
  (Node a b c) == (Node d e f) = a == d
  (Leaf a) == (Leaf b) = a == b
```

Note that now it will compile but there is still a problem: it will raise an error if you check if a `Node … … …` is equal to a `Leaf …` and vice versa. You can add an extra rule for that:

```
instance (Eq n, Eq l) => Eq (Tree n l) where
  (Node a b c) == (Node d e f) = a == d
  (Leaf a) == (Leaf b) = a == b
  _ == _ = False
```

Here you will however consider two `Node … … …` the same, from the moment they wrap the same value. So you do not look to the subtrees. In order to fix this, you need to perform recursion. I leave that as an exericse.

Comment: This hint "instance (Eq n, Eq l) => Eq (Tree n l)" helped a lot. As I understand it, that's the way how you ensure, that == is defined on n and l.

Comment: @Charlie: exactly, you say that there should be equality relations for the types of `n` and `l` in order to define one on `Tree n l`.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that you want exactly that implementation of equality check for your tree.

Let

```
a = Node 2 (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)
b = Node 2 (Leaf 100) (Leaf 200)
```

For such two trees you will get `a == b` as `True` because your comparison of `Node`s compares only the values in that nodes, but the subtrees are ignored. You can even define that portion of your check like this

```
(Node a _ _) == (Node d _ _) = a == d
```

to show that you ignore subtrees.

Maybe this is a desired behavior, but in my opinion, more correct equality check should look like this:

```
(Node x lx rx) == (Node y ly ry) = x == y && lx == ly && rx == ry
```

That will not only check the nodes' values, but also recursively check the subtrees, so `a == b` now will give you `False`, because they're, indeed, different.

Comment: I think Willem's answer did better by leaving this as a hint.

Comment: For the recursion you can use this line:
(Node a b c) == (Node d e f) = a == d && b == e && c == f